# Pandas Pivot table with a Moving Window

Tags: python, pandas

From a Time Series Data which has X Y Z as variables, I would like to take N=5 (configurable) number of instnces and Pivote or Rotate it in out put.

Ex
Input Data

```
TS | X | Y |    Z
---------------
1   1.1 2.1 3.1
2   1.2 2.2 3.2
3   1.3 2.3 3.3
4   1.4 2.4 3.4
5   1.5 2.5 3.5
6   1.6 2.6 3.6
7   1.7 2.7 3.7
8   1.8 2.8 3.8
9   1.9 2.9 3.9
10  2   3   4
..  ..  ..  ..

----------------
```

Output would be X

```
TS  X_1 X_2 ..  X_5     Y_1,Y2  ... Y_5..Z_5
--------------------------------------------
1   1.1 1.2     1.5     2.1,2.2..   ..  3.5
2   1.2 1.3     1.6     2.2,    ..  .. .3.6
3   1.3 .. ..  .Na ..  ... .. Na
-------------------------------------------
```

Comment: *TS* in your output is really the new index. It would not be the same *TS* as in input but actually the suffixed number in columns. Please post your attempted code (SO is not a code-writing service).

Comment: @Parfait, if You see X column in Input and X_1 in output, its Same .
Hence we need not re Set the TS index.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a nested loop solution that involves `.loc` for moving subset of rows, `pivot_table` with handling of column names, `pd.concat` (vertically), and then again `pd_concat` (horizontally).

```
df_list = []
for n in df.columns[1:]:

    inner_list = []
    for i in range(0, len(df)):

        # PIVOT LONG TO WIDE
        pvt_df = (df.loc[i:]                                                  # SUBSET BY ROW
                    .assign(Cols='N' + '_' + (df['TS'] - i).astype(str))      # ADD COUNTER COL
                    .pivot_table(columns='Cols', values=n, aggfunc='max')     # RESHAPE WIDE
                    .reindex(columns=['N_' + str(c) for c in range(1,11)])    # RE-ORDER COLS
                    .set_axis([n + '_' + str(c) for c in range(1,11)],        # RENAME COLS
                              axis='columns', inplace=False)                    
                    .rename_axis(columns=None)                                # REMOVE INDEX NAME
                 )
        inner_list.append(pvt_df)

    # VERTICAL APPEND
    df_list.append(pd.concat(inner_list, ignore_index=True))

# HORIZONTAL MERGE
final_df = pd.concat(df_list, axis='columns')
```

**Output**

```
print(final_df)
#    X_1  X_2  X_3  X_4  X_5  X_6  X_7  X_8  X_9  X_10  Y_1  Y_2  Y_3  Y_4  ...  Y_7  Y_8  Y_9  Y_10  Z_1  Z_2  Z_3  Z_4  Z_5  Z_6  Z_7  Z_8  Z_9  Z_10
# 0  1.1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9   2.0  2.1  2.2  2.3  2.4  ...  2.7  2.8  2.9   3.0  3.1  3.2  3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9   4.0
# 1  1.2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.0   NaN  2.2  2.3  2.4  2.5  ...  2.8  2.9  3.0   NaN  3.2  3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9  4.0   NaN
# 2  1.3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.0  NaN   NaN  2.3  2.4  2.5  2.6  ...  2.9  3.0  NaN   NaN  3.3  3.4  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9  4.0  NaN   NaN
# 3  1.4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  2.4  2.5  2.6  2.7  ...  3.0  NaN  NaN   NaN  3.4  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9  4.0  NaN  NaN   NaN
# 4  1.5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  2.5  2.6  2.7  2.8  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  3.5  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
# 5  1.6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  2.6  2.7  2.8  2.9  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  3.6  3.7  3.8  3.9  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
# 6  1.7  1.8  1.9  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  2.7  2.8  2.9  3.0  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  3.7  3.8  3.9  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
# 7  1.8  1.9  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  2.8  2.9  3.0  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  3.8  3.9  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
# 8  1.9  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  2.9  3.0  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  3.9  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
# 9  2.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  3.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  ...  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN  4.0  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   NaN
```